# Перенос блока под следующую “колонку”, а если не влезает в текущую высоту блока перенести на следующуу колонку

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Есть такой код

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  max-height: 230px;
}
.mega-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.category {
  width: 120px;
}
.category a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="mega-menu">
     <div class="category">
       <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
     </div>
     <div class="category">
       <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 11</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 12</a>
     </div>
      <div class="category">
       <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
     </div>
      <div class="category">
       <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
       <a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если я использую flex они становятся в разные колонки, а мне нужно если у одной колонки есть еще свободное место следующая за ней колонка заполнила это пустое место и при этом не выходила за пределы задоной max-height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подобных примеров лучше использовать CSS Columns

Результат:

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.mega-menu {
  column-count: 4;
}

.category {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.category a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="mega-menu">
    <div class="category">
      <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 11</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 12</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
      <a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. В моем случае лучше сделать columns: auto 150px;